# Why does this print an extra 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code :

```
const horn = () => {
  console.log("Toot");
};
console.log(horn())
```

prints 
Toot
Undefined

Where does undefined comes from?

Comment: you function does not return anything

Comment: @Max is it more accurate to say it returns `undefined`?

Comment: in the eloquentjavascript book, in the console it prints Toot and undefined. Both of them

Comment: if you define a function and it has not a return value then its output is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the return (result) of the function. Even though your function does something inside, it has no return statement (aka doesn't send a result back), therefore you get undefined. If you want to get only 1 "Toot", try this:

```
const horn = () => {
  return "Toot";
};
console.log(horn());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want log in your function, just call horn.

```
const horn = () => {
  console.log("Toot");
};
horn();
```